# Where can I find amulets that goes in the amulet slot?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I was originally under the impression that the amulets that you crafted in Jewelry craft would go into the amulet slot. However when I made it, it would only go into the two accessory slots.

I am now level 80 but my amulet is only level 28. I would really like to upgrade my amulet but can't figure out how.

Does anyone know what type of amulets you can buy that can go into the amulet slot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eh? Jewelers make Amulets.

I'm not sure what else to tell you. If you don't want to make one yourself (or can't!) check the Black Lion Trading House, or Karma Vendors, as I don't think Amulets are very common drops.

[image]

The [accessory slots](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Accessory#Accessory_Slots) you see in the Hero Panel are from left-to-right, top-to-bottom: back, trinket, trinket, **amulet**, ring, and ring. Here's a picture of what you should see in game (notice the amulet bottom-left):

[image: accessory slots]

Comment: Did you try to equip it in your amulet slot? I can craft the amulets but it only fits in the accessory slots.

Comment: Hmm strange I must have made a mistake initially because now i can equip the amulet into my amulet slot. I have no idea what happened. You can close this question.

Comment: @Jay Is it possible you made an earring by mistake? The art sometimes makes them look like amulets, to me at least.

Comment: @Jay I think you may have tried to place your amulet in the "Back" slot. That's a no-go.

Comment: I've gotten one amulet as a drop in 51 levels.

Comment: @Jay Added a description of the slots just in case...